# h:selectBooleanCheckbox not firing a4j:ajax listener inside rich:datatable on first click

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

When checking the `h:selectBooleanCheckBox` the first time, the listener is not fired.  Checking it again, does fire the listener.  I've also tried doing a `valueChangeListener="selectRoleCheckboxChangeListener"` attribute for the `h:selectBooleanCheckBox` with the same result.  It will work on the 2nd and subsequent clicks.  I'd like to have this fire on the first click.  Ideas?  Thanks

```
<rich:dataTable id="roleTable" 
    value="#{roleBean.displayedRoles}" 
    var="roleItem"  
>
    <rich:column 
        id="selectRoleCheckboxColumn" 
    >
        <f:facet name="header">Select Role</f:facet>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
            id="selectRoleCheckbox" 
            value="#{roleItem.selectRole}" 
            binding="#{roleBean.selectRoleCheckbox}"
        >
            <a4j:ajax 
                event="click" 
                listener="#{authorizationBean.selectRoleCheckboxListener}"
            /> 
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: try making the event as `onchange` instead of `click`

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried event="change" but there was no change in behavior.  I'm trying to eliminate the binding to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found the solution for the above problem.

The problem will be either your component doesn't have id's or object or values set are not getting reflected. Another problem would be inner form.

Solution would be...
Set id's for all your component and if the values are not getting reflected on ajax request, render the components for which values are set. Do not have form inside a form.

Hope it should work...

This is a very old post. Still might be useful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectRoleCheckbox" value="#{roleItem.selectRole}"         
  <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{authorizationBean.selectRoleCheckboxListener}"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

hope it works..

Comment: this is RichFaces 4.2, so I'm using a4j:ajax .  This is a migration from RichFaces 3.3.1.  previously using a4j:support.  this worked with a "valueChangeListener" in the component and "event=onclick" in the a4j:support.